# Javascript load theme on page change

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I have written a script to change a site theme trough JS and global vars, as follows:

```js
var theme = "dark";
var themeProperties = ['--bodybgcolor', '--breadcrumbbg', '--navbarbg', '--txtcolor', '--linkcolor', '--linkvisited', '--linkhovercolor', '--navlinkcolor', '--navlinkvisited', '--navlinkhovercolor', '--navlinkbg', '--themebg', '--themeborder', '--iconpos', '--logo', '--cardbg', '--cardLogobg', '--cardshadow', '--cardtxtcolor', '--breadcrumbsvg'];
var themeValues = [['#050505', '#181818', '#050505', '#f1f1f1', '#f1f1f1', '#f1f1f1', '#1BDC88', '#f1f1f1', '#f1f1f1', '#1BDC88', '#5050504d', '#f1f1f1', '#1BDC88', 'left', 'url(../img/logo-sfondo-nero.webp)', '#181818', '#ffffff', '#141414', '#f1f1f1', 'invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(302deg) brightness(101%) contrast(102%)'], 
  ['#ffffff', '#f1f1f1', '#ffffff', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#1BDC88', '#000000', '#000000', '#1BDC88', '#ababab4d', '#000000', '#1BDC88', 'right', 'url(../img/logo-sfondo-bianco.webp)', '#ededed', '#e1e1e1', '#e1e1e1', '#000000', 'invert(0%) sepia(97%) saturate(14%) hue-rotate(160deg) brightness(103%) contrast(102%)']];

window.readyState(setupWindow());
document.readyState(setupPage());

function setupWindow() {
  sessionStorage.setItem('panelTheme', theme);
}

function setupPage() {
  alert(sessionStorage.getItem('panelTheme'));/*this was for debugging in order to know if it was run or not*/
}
function changeTheme() {
  localstTheme = sessionStorage.getItem('panelTheme');
  if (localstTheme == 'dark') {
    theme = 'light';
    setTheme('light');
  } else {
    theme = 'dark';
    setTheme('dark');
  }
}

function setTheme(theme) {
  if (theme == 'dark') {
    sessionStorage.setItem('panelTheme', theme);
    for (var i = 0; i < themeProperties.length; i++) {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(themeProperties[i], themeValues[0][i]);
    }
  }
  if (theme == 'light') {
    sessionStorage.setItem('panelTheme', theme);
    for (var i = 0; i < themeProperties.length; i++) {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty(themeProperties[i], themeValues[1][i]);
    }/**/
  }
}
```

I have to find a way to keep the current theme changed when a new page has been selected throug the html page(eg. i go from home to info). My thinking was to use the sessionStorage variable i've set in order to reset all the global variables to the theme selected ones but I can't do it and I'm currently lost.

setupPage() does not produce the alert and I don't really know why, alert was there to see if it ran correctly on page ready state, before i was using `setTheme(sessionStorage.getItem('panelTheme'))` and was not working

Many thanks to all of you in advance!

Comment: *"My thinking was to use the sessionStorage variable i've set in order to reset all the global variables to the theme selected ones but I can't do it"* - Why can't you do it ?

Comment: Does `setupPage()` produce the alert with the correct value?

Comment: setupPage() does not produce the alert and I don't really know why, alert was there to see if it ran correctly on page ready state, before i was using setTheme(sessionStorage.getItem('panelTheme')) and was not working

Comment: `readyState` is a property, if you want to trigger an event after it changes use [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#readystatechange_as_an_alternative_to_domcontentloaded_event)